# Possibility of simulating a 2D flood for different 2D plan projections for one mesh

Tags: python, flood-fill, gmsh

I am working on a flood simulation should have x,y direction (2D), then I should work on x,z direction (2D). My mesh is the same for both areas (one mesh), where I should connect the flood from an upper area to a lower one.

Is it possible to do so using pyswmm?

(Is it possible to simulate a flood for a 2d mesh but for 2 different plans ( x,y plan and x,z plan) both in the same mesh using pyswmm?)

I am still asking about the possibility of this. My mesh is ready now by using Gmsh.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I haven't started it yet, I am just asking about its possibility then I will start if it is applicable.